# Better way of identifying pairs of natural numbers that satisfy certain conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Recently, I encountered the following problem:

> Let $(a, b)\in(\Bbb{N}^*\space \times\space \Bbb{N}^*)$ such that $$\frac{a^2+2b}{b^2-2a}\text{ and }\frac{b^2+2a}{a^2-2b}$$ are both integers.
>
> *(i)* Show that the absolute difference of $a$ and $b$ is less than or equal to $2$.
>
> *(ii)* Find all the pairs $(a, b)$ with the given properties.
>
> <sup><sub>(From the [National Mathematics Olympiad (Romania), 2012 – Grade 7](http://ssmr.ro/files/onm2012/7_subiect.pdf)).</sub></sup>

The first part (*i*) was quite easy to prove:

$$(b^2-2a)\:\mid\:(a^2+2b)\text{ and }(a^2-2b)\:\mid\:(b^2+2a)$$

Since $(a, b)\in(\Bbb{N}^*\space \times\space \Bbb{N}^*)$, both $a^2+2b$ and $b^2+2a$ are positive, and therefore $b^2-2a\le a^2+2b$ and $a^2-2b\le b^2+2a$. Forming squares of binomials and switching from the RHS to the LHS and backwards:

$$b^2-2b+1\le a^2+2a+1\implies(b-1)^2\le (a+1)^2$$

And since both $a$ and $b$ are positive, the sign does not change when taking the square root: $b-1\le a+1$ so $b\le a+2$. Similarly, but working with the first relation, $a\le b+2$. And thus, $|a-b|\le 2$.

So far so good, but *(ii)* is quite confusing to me, in the sense that I cannot think of an approach that doesn't lead to a lot by-hand checking and "fluffy" arithmetic. My attempt was to consider each case separately, so taking each $a$ in $\{b,\:b+1,\:b+2\}$ (of course assuming $a\ge b$ and then swapping each pair at the end and using what we proved at *(ii)*). Since this method is (naturally) quite lengthy, it makes no sense to include it all in the question, but here are the results I obtained:

> $(a, b) \in \{(1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (6, 6), (2, 4), (4, 2), (3, 5), (5, 3), (4, 6), (6, 4)\}$

I was wondering if there is another, hopefully better way of solving this (*ii*)? <sup><sub>(because this is the solution given by the authors of the problem too :(...)</sub></sup>

Comment: +1 for the well worked solution!

Comment: To be honest, I see no problem in bashing through b) since more or less part a) makes you lean towards this method

Comment: As asdf comments, (i) allows us to consider only a few cases, so I find the method (taking $a=b,b+1,b+2$) natural and easy. One could reduce by-hand checking with the use of some inequalities, and write a "not-lengthy" solution using the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've already commented, I find the method (taking $a=b,b+1,b+2$) natural and easy.

The following solution using the method should not be lengthy.

- If $a=b$, then in order for $$\frac{a^2+2b}{b^2-2a}=\frac{b^2+2a}{a^2-2b}=\frac{a+2}{a-2}=\frac{a-2+4}{a-2}=1+\frac{4}{a-2}$$
  to be an integer, $a-2$ has to be a divisor of $4$, which implies that $a-2=\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4$ giving $a=1,3,4,6$.
- If $a=b+1$, in order for $$\frac{b^2+2a}{a^2-2b}=\frac{b^2+2(b+1)}{(b+1)^2-2b}=\frac{b^2+2b+2}{b^2+1}=\frac{b^2+1+2b+1}{b^2+1}=1+\frac{2b+1}{b^2+1}$$
  to be an integer, $\frac{2b+1}{b^2+1}$ has to be a positve integer, so $$\frac{2b+1}{b^2+1}\ge 1\implies 2b+1\ge b^2+1\implies b\le 2$$For $b=1$, we have $\frac{b^2+2a}{a^2-2b}=\frac 52$ which is not an integer. For $b=2$, we have $\frac{a^2+2b}{b^2-2a}=-\frac{13}{2}$ which is not an integer.
- If $a=b+2$, then$$\frac{b^2+2a}{a^2-2b}=\frac{b^2+2(b+2)}{(b+2)^2-2b}=\frac{b^2+2b+4}{b^2+2b+4}=1$$$$\small P:=\frac{a^2+2b}{b^2-2a}=\frac{(b+2)^2+2b}{b^2-2(b+2)}=1+\frac{8b+8}{b^2-2b-4}=\begin{cases}1+2\cdot\frac{2m+1}{m(m-1)-1}&\text{for even $b=2m$}\\\\1+2^4\cdot \frac{m}{4m(m-2)-1}&\text{for odd $b=2m-1$}\end{cases}$$where $m$ is a positive integer. 
  For $b=1,2,3,4$, $P=-\frac{11}{5},-5,-31,11$ respectively.
  Let us consider the case where $b=2m$ is even with $m\ge 3$. If $m\ge 3$, then $m(m-1)-1\ge 3\cdot 2-1=5$ holds. Since $m(m-1)$ is even, $m(m-1)-1$ is odd. So, in order for $P=1+2\cdot\frac{2m+1}{m(m-1)-1}$ to be an integer, $\frac{2m+1}{m(m-1)-1}$ has to be a positive integer, so we have to have $\frac{2m+1}{m(m-1)-1}\ge 1$, i.e. $2m+1\ge m(m-1)-1$ which implies $m\in\left[\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right]$. With $m\ge 3$, we get $m=3$, and then $(a,b)=(8,6)$ gives $P=\frac{19}{5}$ which is not an integer.
   Let us consider the case where $b=2m-1$ is odd with $m\ge 3$. If $m\ge 3$, then $4m(m-2)-1\ge 4\cdot 3\cdot 1-1=11$ holds. Since $4m(m-2)$ is even, $4m(m-2)-1$ is odd. So, in order for $P=1+2^4\cdot\frac{m}{4m(m-2)-1}$ to be an integer, $\frac{m}{4m(m-2)-1}$ has to be a positive integer, so we have to have $\frac{m}{4m(m-2)-1}\ge 1$, i.e. $m\ge 4m(m-2)-1$ which implies $m\in\left[\frac{9-\sqrt{97}}{8},\frac{9+\sqrt{97}}{8}\right]$. There are no integers $m$ satisfying both this and $m\ge 3$.

Comment: This is my initial method, but it’s good to see other people’s thoughts on the problem. Thank you for your effort (+1)! (If you wouldn’t have posted this, I would have done it anyway)